# PyCharm上でPythonのinput関数が改行コードに続く次の行まで読み込んでしまう。

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, pycharm

Windows7（SP1） に、PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda Plugin 2019.1.3.x64 を最近インストールしました。そこで、Python3.7のコードを動かしていて、input関数が複数あり、標準入力も複数行あるような以下のコードの場合：

```
# coding: utf-8

line1 = input("１行目入力してください：　")
print("１行目：　" + line1)
line2 = input("２行目入力してください：　")
print("２行目：　" + line2)
```

標準入力から次の２行をいっぺんに入力した場合、

```
1111
2222
```

『PyCharmでの通常の実行』をすると、変数 line1 の中にいっぺんに「line1='1111\n2222'」と読み込まれてしまうのです（改行コードで止まりません）。何か設定などを変えて、intput関数が正常に機能するような対処方法などがありましたら教えてください。（以下はPythonコンソールの出力です）

```
１行目入力してください：　>? 1111
... 2222
１行目：　1111
2222
２行目入力してください：　>? 
２行目：
```

なお、同じPyCharmの環境でデバッグモード（緑の虫のボタン）では、input関数は改行コード「\n」までの１行しか読み込まないというように正常に動作をします（下は正常に動作したデバッガーのコンソール画面出力）。

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.5728.105)
１行目入力してください：　１行目：　1111
２行目入力してください：　２行目：　2222
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

公式のサポートには、ライセンス契約を結んでいないと質問できないと言われたので、ここで質問させていただきました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

回答ではなく別環境での検証結果です。
下記の環境ではデバッグモードと通常実行で同一の動作をしました。

> PyCharm 2019.2 (Community Edition)
> Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64
> VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> Windows 10 Home 64bit 1803
> Virtualenv
> Python 3.6.0

※`\n`は改行文字に読み替えてください。

#### `1111\n2222\n`をコピペした時の挙動

```
１行目入力してください：　1111
2222
１行目：　1111
２行目入力してください：　２行目：　2222

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### `1111\n2222`をコピペした時の挙動(末尾の改行なし)

```
１行目入力してください：　1111
2222１行目：　1111
２行目入力してください：
```

#### その後Enterキーを押した後の表示

```
１行目入力してください：　1111
2222１行目：　1111
２行目入力してください：　
２行目：　2222

Process finished with exit code 0
```

もしかしたらOS, 仮想環境, PyCharmバージョンの変更で問題が解消するかもしれません。

Comment: payaneco様　検証ありがとうございました。２つ目の改行コードを付けてやってみました。（この欄にはコードが書けない（？）ようなので、回答欄に書きます。）

Answer (score 0):

payneco様の検証と同じように、２つ目の改行コードを付けてやってみても上手くいきませんでした。ペーストした後に、２回エンターを押しています。２つ目の改行コードは画面上では見当たりません。

[image: 変数の中身]

```
3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
１行目入力してください：　>? 1111
2222
１行目：　1111
2222
２行目入力してください：　>? 
２行目：
```

そこで、入力データに３行目を追加してみました。

```
1111
2222
3333
```

実行すると下のようになります。変数の中身は

[image: 変数の中身（入力データが３行の時）]

```
１行目入力してください：　>? 1111
... 2222
... 3333
... 
１行目：　1111
2222
3333
２行目入力してください：　>? 
２行目：
```

当面の間、いっぺんに入力しないか、デバッグモードで実行するかで回避していこうと思います。
ありがとうございました。